# What is the difference between implicit and explicit stochastic gradient descent?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, stochastic-gradient-descent

While reading the [implicit stochastic gradient descent](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stochastic_gradient_descent#/Extensions_and_variants), I get stuck by its update:

$$w^{new}:=w^{old} - \eta \nabla Q_{i} (w^{new}) $$

I learned from [this slide](http://www.machinelearning.ru/wiki/images/b/b6/ChabanenkoImplicitSagSlides.pdf#page=5) that the above is the implicit style of SGD which can be written as this:

$$\theta_{k+1} = \theta_k - \gamma_k \nabla_k f_i(\theta_{k+1})$$

But I wonder how we can use $\theta_{k+1}$ before even defining it? How does it differ from the explicit stochastic gradient descent in implementation? Why do we need implicit SGD? A simple example for illustration would be very appreciated.

Comment: One method is suggested in the description of SAG a few slides further. at each step you iterate until the implicit equation is achieved (eg starting with regular gradient descent step as initial guess???).  The problem I believe its aiming to tackle is a high condition number for your Hessian of the objective function - causing high curvature in certain directions and low curvature in others. which means you need a very small learning rate (to not oscillate in high curvature, but then slow convergence in low curvature directions)

Answer (score 1):

> ...how we can use $\theta_{k+1}$ before even defining it?

It's actually defined by the update rule:

$$
\theta_{k+1} = \theta_k - \gamma_k \nabla f(\theta_{k+1})
$$

What you do is you *search* for a $\theta_{k+1}$ that satisfies this equation. You could also rewrite this as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\text{Find }\theta_{k+1}\text{ such that:}\\
&h(\theta_{k+1}) = \theta_{k+1} - \left[ \theta_k - \gamma_k \nabla f(\theta_{k+1}) \right] = 0
\end{aligned}
$$

To solve this, one could use any root finding method, including fixed-point iteration, as suggested in the comments:

1. Start from a guess $\theta_{k+1}^{(0)}$.
2. Update the guess: $\theta_{k+1}^{(1)} = h(\theta_{k+1}^{(0)})$.
3. Loop step (2) until $\theta_{k+1}^{(n)}$ stops changing.
4. You found $\theta_{k+1} \equiv \theta_{k+1}^{(n)}$.

Each step of such a fixed-point iteration requires evaluation of the gradient $\nabla f(\theta_{k+1}^{(n)})$, which could be really computationally intensive.

---

> Why do we need implicit SGD?

The paper below shows that:

1. Implicit *and* explicit SGD are asymptotically unbiased (Theorem 4.1).
2. Both algorithms provide the same asymptotic efficiency (Thm. 4.2).
3. Similarly to implicit Euler method for solving differential equations, *implicit* SGD is more stable (section 4.3):

> ...in the standard SGD procedure, the effect from the initial conditions can be amplified in an exponentially large way before fading out, if the learning rate is misspecified...
>
> ...the effects of the initial conditions **monotonically decrease** in the implicit method...

Seems like the main advantage of implicit SGD compared to the regular explicit one is increased stability of the algorithm.

### References

- Toulis, Panagiotis, Jason Rennie, and Edoardo M Airoldi. 2014. "Statistical Analysis of Stochastic Gradient Methods for Generalized Linear Models." In Proceedings of the 31st International Conference on Machine Learning, edited by Eric P. Xing and Tony Jebara, 32:667–75. Bejing, China: PMLR. https://proceedings.mlr.press/v32/toulis14.html.